# Put a switch in a viewHolder - Custom List in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have created an APP, a personalized list that is inflated with data from a WebService, as you see one of its fields is state, but this returns you in number (0,1,2) what I want to do is put it in "VACANTE "," OCCUPIED "," RESERVED "and that is achieved through a switch, but I do not know how to apply it

```
viewHolder.estado.setText(items.get(i).getEstado());//number (0,1,2)
```

This data I pull it from a PHP WebService This is my current code:

```
public class MetaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MetaAdapter.MetaViewHolder>
        implements ItemClickListener {

    /**
     * Lista de objetos {@link Meta} que representan la fuente de datos
     * de inflado
     */
    private List<Plaza> items;

    /*
    Contexto donde actua el recycler view
     */
    private Context context;


    public MetaAdapter(List<Plaza> items, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MetaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_list, viewGroup, false);
        return new MetaViewHolder(v, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MetaViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.nivel.setText(items.get(i).getNivel());
        viewHolder.estado.setText(items.get(i).getEstado());
        viewHolder.colegio.setText(items.get(i).getIe());
        viewHolder.especialidad.setText(items.get(i).getEspecialidad());
        viewHolder.codigo.setText(items.get(i).getCodigoPlaza());
    }


    /**
     * Sobrescritura del método de la interfaz {@link ItemClickListener}
     *
     * @param view     item actual
     * @param position posición del item actual
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        DetailActivity.launch(
                (Activity) context, items.get(position).getPlazaID());
    }


    public static class MetaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener {
        // Campos respectivos de un item
        public TextView nivel;
        public TextView estado;
        public TextView colegio;
        public TextView especialidad;
        public TextView codigo;
        public ItemClickListener listener;


        public MetaViewHolder(View v, ItemClickListener listener) {
            super(v);
            nivel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nivel);
            estado = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.estado);
            colegio = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.colegio);
            especialidad = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.especialidad);
            codigo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.codigo);
            this.listener = listener;
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}


    interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

Currently in my application looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Do you just want to display the state as `String` (like "VACANTE" instead of "0") or do you want to add a GUI element that lets you switch the state for every list item?

Comment: Just replace as String (like "VACANTE" instead of "0")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MetaViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
       switch (items.get(i).getEstado()) {
        case "0":
            return viewHolder.estado.setText("VACANTE");
        case "1":
            return viewHolder.estado.setText("OCCUPIED");
        case "2":
           return viewHolder.estado.setText("RESERVED");
        default:
           return viewHolder.estado.setText("");
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to apply a String for every state, e.g.

```
public String getStateAsString(int state) {
    switch (state) {
        case 0:
            return "VACANTE";
        case 1:
            return "OCCUPIED";
        case 2:
           return "RESERVED";
        default:
           return "STATE NOT DEFINED";
    }
}
```

and call that method instead of directly assigning the state as `int` to your TextView:

```
/* 
 * Instead of 
 * viewHolder.codigo.setText(items.get(i).getCodigoPlaza());
 * you do the following
 */
int stateAsInt = items.get(i).getCodigoPlaza();
String stateAsString = getStateAsString(stateAsInt);
viewHolder.estado.setText(state);
```